# Deleting a project in SVN with Subclipse

Tags: svn, version-control, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I would like to completely remove a project from version control from inside Eclipse using the [Subclipse plug-in](http://subclipse.tigris.org).

My requirement is similar to the one at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512124/how-can-i-do-a-svn-delete-keep-local-from-subclipse) except that I don't want to keep the local files either.

The **Team** context menu doesn't offer anything promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you will have to do this the hard way from the command line. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re08.html

Comment: Tank you, Navi, that is the way I ended up using. Unfortunately there seems to be no proper way to do it from subclipse (at least for top-level projects, see Raghuram's answer)

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I did too.. Though I first disconnected the resources from the SVN server and then committed them as though they were completely new, in to the desired spot. This kind of mucks up the work-flow for tracking changes within a specific document from before the move. But whatever.

Answer (score 14):

Go to

```
Window - Show view - Svn repositories
```

You can then right click on folders and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete all the files and folders that you want from Eclipse and then do `Team -> Commit...` . This will delete the project from Eclipse as well as remove it locally.

Comment: Thank you, Raghuram, it didnt work for me, at least not for the top-level project : if i delete the project, there is nothing i can select the Team->Commit on. It could work for a subproject though